# Meteor - Isotope doesn’t work with nested templates

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze, jquery-isotope

I’m trying to integrate Isotope with my Meteor App, but I’ve been having some complications. When I use directly html inside my Isotope container it works fine, but when I try using nested templates, Isotope doesn’t work. Here is what I have at the moment.

**Home.html**

```
<template name="home">
  <div class="grid">
    {{> card }}
  </div>
</template>
```

**Home.js**

```
import './home.html';

Template.home.onRendered ( function() {

      $('.grid').isotope({
        // options
        itemSelector: '.grid-item',
        layoutMode: 'masonry',
        masonry: {
          gutter: 24
        }
      });
 });
```

**Card.html**

```
<template name="card">

  {{#each publications}}
    <div class="grid-item">
      <div class="card-margin">
        <img src="{{avatar}}" alt="" class="avatar"/>
        <div class="name"> {{username}} <div class="dropdown"><a>></a><div class="dropdown-content">{{#if isOwner}}<button class="delete">&times;</button> <button class="edit">Edit</button>{{else}}<button>Report</button> <button>Unfollow</button>{{/if}}</div></div></div>
        <div class="date" id="date-show">{{customDate}} </div>
        <p class="card">
            {{ pub }}
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: Perhaps `home` is rendered before the publication data is available in which case there may not be any `.grid-items` ready yet? Have you tried putting the masonry code in `card.onRendered()` instead?

Comment: I've updated my answer, perhaps another option will suit you better.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I've tried the Styx's answer and it works. You were right, my nested template was loading after my home template, so Isotope didn't find my grid-items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem itself is that your `home` template is rendered *before* its nested templates. Thus, there are no any `.grid-item` elements.

The only way to solve that in your situation is to postpone initializing `.isotope(...)` using [`Meteor.defer()`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/core.html#Meteor-defer) or [`Meteor.setTimeout()`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/timers.html#Meteor-setTimeout) in hopes that that would give nested templates enough time to render:

```js
Template.home.onRendered(function() {
  Meteor.setTimeout(function() {
    $('.grid').isotope({
      // options
    });
  }, 250);
```

**Added**:

Another option would be for nested templates to notify its parent from their `onRendered` functions:

**`Main template`**:

```js
Template.home.onCreated(function() {
  this.renderGrid = _.debounce(() => {
    $('.grid').isotope({
      // options
    });
  }, 250);
});

Template.home.events({
  'ready.griditem .grid'(e, tpl) {
    tpl.renderGrid();
  }
});
```

**`Nested template`**:

```js
Template.card.onRendered(function() {
  $('.grid').trigger('ready.griditem');
});
```

Comment: It works! Thanks Styx, with set time to 200 works perfectly.

Comment: I would really prefer to use onRender instead of timeout. Usage of timeouts might reduce the responsiveness of your UI/

Comment: @Alex Well, I take that  `isotope` should initialize all nested templates simultaneously. They can't all have `.isotope()` inside their `onRendered`.